# Angular2 accessing binding instance variable within callback

Tags: javascript, angular, electron

In angular2 I have the following component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

const dialog = require("electron").dialog;
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const fs = require("fs");
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

@Component({
  selector: 'ct-config-editor',
  templateUrl: 'config.editor.component.html'
})
export class ConfigEditorComponent {

  constructor() {
    this.selected_file = 'Max';
  }


  clicked(event){
    alert("lol");
      ipc.send('open-file-dialog');

      ipc.on('selected-directory', function (event, path) {
        this.selected_file = `You selected: ${path}`;
      });
  }
}
```

The view has a correctly bound property called selected_file like this :

```
<h1>{{selected_file}}</h1>
```

The value of the H1 is max at the start -- however after my callback runs, I don't have access to the `this.selected_file` because the context of the 'this' is not my class.

How do I access my instance variable within the callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrow function to retain context:

```
ipc.on('selected-directory', (event, path) => {
   this.selected_file = `You selected: ${path}`;
});
```

This way `this` will be referenced to your class

See also more details here

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this

Comment: Is this the best practice? I don't particularly understand what the arrow function is doing!